# Volcanic Cones - Fissure Type

Tags: volcanology, geomorphology, mountain-building

Can [volcanic cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcanic_cone), similar to the one shown below form from fissure type of volcanoes?

[image]

Comment: it is expected that you do a minimum of research before asking a question here on earth science.